# isiOSAppOnMac vs. isMacCatalystApp?

Tags: ios, macos, uikit, mac-catalyst

I have an app that runs on target "My Mac (Designed for iPad)" and also presets in the Mac App Store as an iPad app. This requires Apple Silicon, also, so... [it's not catalyst](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/running-your-ios-apps-in-macos)? Does it have a name? How is catalyst different in implementation? Does Catalyst require switching from UIKit to AppKit?

I see there are two flags here:

```
extension ProcessInfo {
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    open var isMacCatalystApp: Bool { get }

    @available(iOS 14.0, *)
    open var isiOSAppOnMac: Bool { get }
}
```

Comment: Catalyst allows you to use ios source code but release it is as a Mac app. It doesn't require you to use AppKit, but you must build and release a specific Mac app, either via the Mac App Store or some other distribution method. The "designed for iPad" approach allows Mx Mac users to install and run your iOS app directly. It doesn't require a separate build and submission to the App Store. You can simply check the box in App Store Connect to make it available to Mac users

Comment: Thanks muchly @Paulw11! So with Catalyst it must be a separate App Store listing, but... any way to have them share IAPs/subs? I'm guessing that's impossible, since they cannot share the same bundle ID, right?

Comment: @DanRosenstark I just added a little extra to my answer below. The iOS and macOS builds (via Mac Catalyst) are part of the same app and they share IAPs.

Comment: @HangarRash thanks this is kinda blowing my mind.

"As of Xcode 11.4, new apps built with Mac Catalyst can use the same bundle ID as the iPad app to support universal purchase. If you don't want to distribute the apps together, you can register a different bundle ID."

it's all quite confusing but I think I get the map now. It would be nice to remove the "Design for iPad" out of the App Store listing. I wonder if the app would appear in the "Mac Apps" tab instead of the "iPhone & iPad apps" tab?

Comment: @DanRosenstark I have an app that was iOS only with support for running as an iPad app on Apple Silicon Macs. I later changed it to use Mac Catalyst. The whole "Design for iPad" went away and any user that had that version on their Mac received the new Mac Catalyst version the next time they updated. The updated app appears under Mac Apps.

Comment: Thanks, @HangarRash and others, this is all extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Mac (Designed for iPad)" app is just an iPad app. Apple Silicon Macs can run iPad apps as-is. The app looks and works just like it does on the iPad. Such an app requires no additional work but it also does not take any advantage of any macOS features nor does it have the exact same look-and-feel of a native macOS app.

A "Mac (Mac Catalyst)" app is still written (mostly) in UIKit but it allows your app to run on Intel and Apple Silicon Macs. It starts out as your same iPad app. But you now have the ability to make it look and work a bit more like a native macOS app. It can make use of some AppKit APIs (only those specifically indicated as supporting Mac Catalyst). You need to specifically build and submit the macOS version of your iOS app. Even though you post two separate builds, they are part of the same app and share the same setup such as in-app purchases.

`isiOSAppOnMac` only returns true when your "Designed for iPad" iOS app is running on an Apple Silicon Mac.

`isMacCatalystApp` returns true if your "Designed for iPad" iOS app is running on an Apple Silicon Mac or when your "Mac Catalyst" iOS app is running on any Mac.

See [Mac Catalyst](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst) in the documentation for complete details.